# ASP.NET- Sharing a static dictionary between a thread and main thread (localhost x server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

I'm using webforms.

I'm using a static dictionary to pass data from the thread to the main thread. The problem is that the main thread cannot see the data added by the thread.

Now, the funny thing is that **it works when running on localhost, but not when i publish it to the server.**

Here is my code:

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> staticDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

//start thread
protected void validtionStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (obj != null)
                return;
            lock (((IDictionary)staticDictionary).SyncRoot)//also tried without this
            {
                obj = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ValidateImport));
                obj.IsBackground = false;//also tried true
                obj.Start();
            }

        }

protected void ReadThread()
         {
            staticDictionary["mykey"];//always null
         }
```

Thanks.

**Edit --- 
More information:**

-The user loads the page
- Clicks a button -> Background thread is fired.
- Javascript on page queries the server from time to time, the server returns the data   read from the thread. (this is what i call main thread, the request handler)

Comment: Why don't you use Session for this?

Comment: I did at first, but i fall in the same problem. (i.e works on localhost only)

Comment: I have delete for while the answer because I look your code and I have confuse now, what are you try to archive ? maybe the solution is something simple.

Comment: I want to pass data from the background thread to the main one. I'm currently trying your answer.

Comment: Who calls `ReadThread`? What does the code look like in `ValidateImport`. How is the "main thread" using `staticDictionary`? Also, what is "the thread" and how is it different from the "main thread"? You need to provide more information.

Comment: Please provide the code of ValidateImport